# switching between newcommand and default

Tags: tables, macros

I've defined the following macro:

```
% makes tables more readable  
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}  
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
```

Which add extra tabbing space in the tables. However, in one place in my report I need to use the default as it messes up the structure of the page (I have a side-by-side table and figures). I wonder if I could, for some table environments, reset the tabbing space to default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a command to store the old length so you can go back to it later. For lengths, you could do like this:

```
\newlength{\myparindent}
\setlength{\myparindent}{\parindent}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

%restore original
\setlength{\parindent}{\myparindent}
```

Answer (score 4):

Store the modifying macros in a macro that you can call where you need it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Store modifiable content
\newlength{\storetabcolsep}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\storearraystretch\arraystretch% \arraystretch
  \setlength{\storetabcolsep}{\tabcolsep}% \tabcolsep
}

% Makes tables more readable
\newcommand{\increasetablespace}{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}}%
% Restore stretching defaults
\newcommand{\restoretablespace}{%
  \let\arraystretch\storearraystretch% \arraystretch
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{\storetabcolsep}}% \tabcolsep

\begin{document}

\increasetablespace
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \hline
  A & B & C \\
  \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\restoretablespace
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \hline
  A & B & C \\
  \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to store any content that you potentially modify within the document `\AtBeginDocument`. Then, via macro calls `\increasetablespace` they're updated to suit your stretched-out needs, and restored using `\restoretablespace`.

Comment: i'd be inclined to call it `\defaulttablespace` (even if it's hard to spell correctly) instead of `\restoretablespace`, since the latter might imply i'm restoring it to some alternate that i've defined that isn't the default.